# CSS background-images onload check

Tags: jquery, css

Im using http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/ imagesLoaded plugin which works great for detecting when a div's images have loaded:

```
$('.background').imagesLoaded(function() {
console.log('background loaded');
});
```

I need this to also check when a background-image applied via CSS has been loaded as the above plugin doesnt seem to listen for background-images.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('<img>').attr('href', 'urlHere.jpg').imagesLoaded(function(){
   console.log('backgroundImage loaded, apply as BG');
});` might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **waitForImages** plugin, it can detect loading of images referenced in the CSS.

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: thanks @Michael Samteladze, this looks like a good plugin but having a few issues with it. I have 20 divs with background images on. I can set this plugin to check for when each divs images are loaded. but when each call is made to say a div is ready i cannot reference the div, only the image object.

Comment: @TomD The `this` should be a reference to the image. If it's not, please file an [issue](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/issues).

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in this plugin, but there is a workaround, Please read darcyclarke comment in this page https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/29